# Gradle sync task inconsistency

Tags: java, gradle

I am trying to copy dependencies of a java project to `lib` folder and then generating value of `Class-Path` attribute in `manifest.mf` from the list of jars copied to `lib` folder.

Here is `build.gradle` file -

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

libsDirName = 'package'

ext {
    libDir = file('build/dependencies/lib')
}

task syncDependencies(type: Sync) {
    from  configurations.runtime
    into  libDir
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
            "Class-Path": libDir.listFiles().collect { 'lib/' + it.getName() }.join(' ')
        )
    }
}

jar.dependsOn syncDependencies

dependencies {
    //external compile dependencies
    compile 'org.eclipse.persistence:javax.persistence:2.1.0'
}
```

When I execute `gradle clean jar`, it copies dependencies to `lib` folder but value of `Class-Path` attribute is blank. If I execute `gradle clean jar` again, it generates proper value for `Class-Path` attribute.

However if i execute `gradle clean` followed by `gradle clean jar`, value of `Class-Path` is again empty.

I am using `Gradle 2.6`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the `Class-Path` attribute remains empty when first executing `gradle clean jar` is that you mix up the [build lifecycle phases](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html).

`libDir.listFiles().collect { 'lib/' + it.getName() }.join(' ')` is evaluated when the project is configured whereas the `lib` directory is filled by the `syncDependencies` task when the project is executed.

In order to set the `Class-Path` attribute correctly, in the *configuration phase* you can do:

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
            "Class-Path": configurations.runtime.collect { "lib/$it.name" }.join(' ')
        )
    }
}
```

Alternatively the following can still be done in the *execution phase*:

```
jar {
    doFirst {
        manifest {
            attributes(
                "Class-Path": libDir.listFiles().collect { 'lib/' + it.getName() }.join(' ')
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Understanding what executes during configuration phase and what executes during execution phase is the toughest part of gradle (at least for me).